# (Python GUI)How can I write short and efficient code

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I wrote a program that moves the hexagon shape by the number of times.
but I think that It looks dirty.
So I want to reduce the length and I want to write efficiently, is this the best?

```
import time
from tkinter import*
tk = Tk()
canvas=Canvas(tk, width=1000, height=1000, background="black")
canvas.pack()
canvas.create_polygon(300,200,300,250,340,225,fill="yellow")

k = int(input("input value"))
for q in range(0,k):    
    for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,5,0)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,5,5)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,-5,5)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,-5,0)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,-5,-5)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,5,-5)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,5,5)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,-5,5)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,-5,0)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,-5,-5)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
for x in range(0,10):
    canvas.move(1,5,-5)
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.03)
```

Move the above code in a function so that you wont write a redundant code

```
def TKUptake(minRange, maxRange, CanvasMove, sleepTime):
    """
    minRange : (Int) Min range for list = 0
    maxRange : (Int) Max range for list = 10
    CanvasMove : Dict for canvas move
    canvasMove[x]= 1
    canvasMove[y]= 5
    canvasMove[z]=-5
    """
    for x in range(minRange, maxRange):
        canvas.move(CanvasMove[x],CanvasMove[y],CanvasMove[z])
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

Comment: Hi @LinuxUbuntu if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.